# how to find the subfolder in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

how to find the subfolder in the director in coldfusion

I did in cfdirectory . It shows the all files not the folder

this is my code

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop index = "i" from = "1" to = "3">
    <cfdirectory
        action = "list"
        directory = "#myarray[i]#"
        name = "files"
        filter="*.*"
        type="all">
        <cfset d="#files.recordcount#">
        <cfoutput>
            #d#
        </cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm having trouble understanding what it is you're trying to do. If you just want to list the subdirectories of a directory, why not use `type="dir"`?

Comment: The value of your `filter` attribute will only return items that have a `.` somewhere in the name, this is likely why you are not seeing folders. If you want files AND folders, remove the `filter` attribute. If you ONLY want folders, do what @AlEverett suggested.

Comment: thank u i got by using type="dir"

Comment: The nested `<cfoutput>` also looks strange